# Using version control accross production and test environments

Tags: git, version-control, hpc

We have two physically separated management servers for two separate computer clusters (all systems run CentOS 8) and both management servers running [xcat](https://xcat.org/).  One  is a test environment (call `test`) and the other is the production (call `prod`) environment.  They are ALMOST identical, but there are some important file system related differences that must be maintained between the management servers.

We first test a new system change in `test`, check that nothing is broken, and then roll it out to `prod`.  There is a directory, `/install/`, on both management servers that contains the `xcat` configuration files. When a change is made in `/install/`, we copy those changes to another directory (on the same management server), called `/backup_install`.

On both management servers (i.e. `test` and `prod`), `/backup_install` is version controlled with `git`.

So a typical change might go like :

1. Change a configuration file in `/install` on the `test` management server
2. Roll the change out to the `test` cluster
3. Check the integrity of the `test` cluster
4. If its OK, copy changes on `test` management server from `/install` to `/backup_install`
5. Commit the changes in `/backup_install` with `git`
6. `rsync` the changes in `/install` from `test` management server to `/install` on `prod` management server
7. Copy changes on `prod` management server from `/install` to `/backup_install`
8. Commit the changes in `/backup_install` on `prod` with git

Frequently, users forget to commit changes in `/backup_install` on one of the management servers.

One thought I had was to put `/install` under version control, instead of `/backup_install`. However, `xcat` / `confluent`, use those directories directly and I'm mildly paranoid about putting unexpected things (e.g. `.git`) in directories used by tools that I don't fully understand.

**Question** :
We are clumsily maintaining two separate git repos on very similar systems on two different management servers.  Is there a more efficient, less error prone way of doing this?

Comment: If you are going to vote it down, you should at least give some feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `.git/` directory somewhere else, and instruct git to use that other location as its database :

```
git --git-dir=/backup_install/.git --work-tree=/install status
git --git-dir=/backup_install/.git --work-tree=/install add file1 file2 ...
git --git-dir=/backup_install/.git --work-tree=/install commit
```

You can also indicate these values using the `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variables.

See the doc for the [--git-dir option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---git-dirltpathgt).

You can use these to create appropriate aliases or scripts for your use case.